# Unpacking IO ByteString in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying to do some image manipulation in Haskell with an image library. Opening the image with the library requires a `ByteString` type. I want to test the library in ghci but when I load a file it has the type `IO ByteString` and cannot be used.

How can I unpack the `ByteString` data from the `IO ByteString` type in ghci?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fmap` teaches pure functions how to muck about with impure inputs:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

and `(=<<)` teaches impure functions how to muck about with impure inputs:

```
(=<<) :: (a -> IO b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

And, of course, in ghci, there is the handy `do`-notation available as a shorthand for uses of `(=<<)`, so that if you write

```
> x <- Data.ByteString.readFile "/path/to/image.jpg"
```

then you will have `x :: ByteString` bound in the remainder of your session, even though `Data.ByteString.readFile "/path/to/image.jpg" :: IO ByteString`.